# how to set CrystalReport document path as DataSet in asp.net 3.5

Tags: crystal-reports, asp.net-3.5

i'm .net developer. here i just want to set CrstalReport Document Path as Dataset. here i's my code:

```
 ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
 reportdocument.SetDataSource(myDataSet);
 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
```

here error occured at SetDataSource(myDataset) line like:

```
Server Error in '/EasyWeb' Application.
Invalid report file path.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: Invalid report file path.

Source Error:


Line 1652:                    }
Line 1653:                    myDataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
Line 1654:                    reportdocument.SetDataSource(myDataSet);
Line 1655:                    break;
Line 1656:                case "Outbox":


Source File: f:\EasyWeb\EndUser\Post_History.aspx.cs    Line: 1654

Stack Trace:


[LoadSaveReportException: Invalid report file path.]
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.EngineExceptionUtils.DoThrowException(String message, EngineExceptionErrorID id) +89
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ExceptionThrower.ThrowEngineException(String messageID, EngineExceptionErrorID id) +269
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) +340
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.EnsureLoadReport() +175
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type) +89
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataSet dataSet) +115
   EndUser_FS_File_History.lbut_print_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\EasyWeb\EndUser\Post_History.aspx.cs:1654
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +79
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

where i'm gone wrong here....

**--------------------------------------Updated----------------------------------------------------**

here is my LINQ code:

```
 var query1 = from p in db.Posts
                                 join c in db.Categories on p.Category_id equals c.Id
                                 join u in db.Users on p.User_id equals u.Id
                                 where (p.ToUser_id == user_id || p.ToUser_id == null) && p.User_id != user_id && (p.group_id == group_id || p.group_id == null) && (p.status_id == int.Parse(Session["status_id"].ToString()) || p.status_id == null)
                                 orderby p.Sent_Datetime descending
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Id = p.Id,
                                     Title = p.Title,
                                     Publisher = u.First_name + " " + u.Last_name,
                                     PublishDate = p.Sent_Datetime,
                                     IsFile = p.IsFileAttached,
                                     CategoryName = c.Category_name,
                                     FileSize = p.TotalFileSize
                                 };
                    foreach (var item in query1)
                    {
                        if (item != null)
                        {
                            var query1_1 = from f in db.Flags
                                           where f.Post_History_id == item.Id && f.User_id == user_id
                                           select new
                                           {
                                               IsImp = f.IsImportant,
                                               IsTrashed = f.IsTrashed,
                                               IsRemoved = f.IsRemoved
                                           };
                            bool IsIns = true;
                            bool IsImp = false;
                            foreach (var item1 in query1_1)
                            {
                                if (item1 != null)
                                {
                                    if (item1.IsTrashed == true || item1.IsRemoved == true)
                                    {
                                        IsIns = false;
                                    }
                                    if (item1.IsImp != null)
                                    {
                                        IsImp = bool.Parse(item1.IsImp.ToString());
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (IsIns == true)
                            {
                                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                                dr["Id"] = item.Id.ToString();
                                dr["IsImp"] = IsImp;
                                dr["Title"] = item.Title.ToString();
                                dr["Publisher"] = item.Publisher.ToString();
                                dr["PublishDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(item.PublishDate.ToString());
                                dr["IsFile"] = bool.Parse(item.IsFile.ToString());
                                dr["CategoryName"] = item.CategoryName.ToString();
                                dr["FileSize"] = item.FileSize.ToString();
                                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    myDataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this after declaration.

```
reportdocument.Load("FilePath");
```

your error shows.

```
Server Error in '/EasyWeb' Application.
Invalid report file path.
```

means either you have not specified report path or given path is invalid.

Comment: i just want to filter this record with dataset

Comment: but how can you show report without defining a report path or created report object.

Comment: ok..it's helped me lot. here i just want to filter record with LINQ query and this result store in DataSet. Is that way to SetDataSource as Dataset.

Comment: DataSet is the collection of DataTable. when you are trying to assign dataset in SetDataSource that means included tables in dataset must be exists in created report. can you place your LINQ query code where your dataset has filled.

Comment: OK, Set the table name same as included table in your crystal report. `dt.TableName='TableName'` before `myDataSet.Tables.Add(dt);`. this will be used to map the table in crystal report with dataset.

Comment: Here are u suggested Database Table name.

Comment: no the name of table which you have selected in crystal report.